# Better way to "mutex" than with a .lock file over the network?

Tags: powershell, locking, mutex

I have a small setup consisting of *n* clients (CL0, CL1, ... CL*n*) that access a windows share on the server.

On that server a json file holds important data that needs to be read- and writable by all players in the game. It holds key value pairs that are constantly read and changed:

```
{
    "CurrentActive":  "CL1",
    "DataToProcess":  false,
    "NeedsReboot":  false,
    "Timestamp":  "2020-05-25 16:10"
}
```

I already got the following done with PowerShell: 
if a client writes the file, a lock file is generated that holds the hostname and the timestamp of the access. After the access, the lock file is removed. Each write "job" first checks if there is a lockfile and if the timestamp is still valid and will then conditionally write to the file after the lock is removed.

```
#Some Pseudo Code:
if(!Test-Path $lockfile){
  gc $json
}else{
  #wait for some time and try again
  #check if lock is from my own hostname
  #check if timestamp in lock is still valid
}
```

This works ok, but is very complex to build up, since I needed to implement the lock-mechanism and also a way to force remove the lock when the client is not able to remove the file for multiple reasons a.s.o. (and I am sure I also included some errors...). Plus, in some cases reading the file will return an empty one. I assume this is in the sweetspot during the write of the file by another client, when it is flushed and then filled with the new content.

I was looking for other options such as mutex and it works like a charm on a single client with multiple threads, but since relying on SafeHandles in the scope of one system, not with multiple clients over the network. Is it possible to get mutex running over the network with

I also stumbled about AlphaFS which would allow me to do transactional processing on the filesystem, but that doesn't fix the root cause that multiple clients access one file at the same time.

Is there a better way to store the data? I was thinking about the Windows Registy but I could not find anything on mutex there.

Any thoughts highly appreciated!

Comment: What are your performance requirements? The best way here would be to provide an API endpoint (using PowerShell JEA for example) for the clients to submit their updates to, and then handle file access with a proper mutex server-side

Comment: all clients are running a GUI that will be able to show (and also change) the mentioned in the json file. So performance needs to be end-user-friendly. In the current solution I am running a endless while loop that runs with a sleep time of 200ms.